# Java 8: How to get a value from a list contained as a map value?

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following situation:
I have a LinkedHashMap<> where the key type is a String and the values types varies: double, String, LinkedHashMap, etc.
I am trying to extract a value from a key of one of the LinkedHashMaps values which are a value of the main map.
For example, I'd like to get the result 1 from the following code (obviously it is a mess since it doesn't even compile):

```
Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();     
input.put("a", "1234");
input.put("b", "2345");
input.put("c", "3456");
input.put("d", new HashMap<String, String>());

HashMap<String, Object> input2 = (HashMap<String, Object>)(input.get("d"));
input2.put("d1", 1);
input2.put("d2", 2);

Optional<Integer> result = input.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("d"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("d1"))
            .findFirst();
```

Where do I go wrong, and of course, what is the best way to get the result?

Thanks.

Comment: `Integer result = ((Map)input.getOrDefault("d", Collections.emptyMap())).get("d1");`

Comment: @Holger That's great! I only needed to add an Integer casting to the right hand expression. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you expecting more than one keys of the map to equal "d"?

Answer (score 5):

Once you use a `Map` with different value (and even key) types (and worse, *nested* maps). Then I suggest taking a step back and try to analyse what you've done. It seems that you're way better with a `class` than a `Map`. An example with your keys:

```
class YourClass {
    String a;
    String b;
    String c;
    YourOtherClass d;
}

class YourOtherClass {
    Integer d1;
    Integer d2;
}
```

I've omitted getters, setters and constructors for simplicity.

You can then create instances of those objects, like this:

```
YourOtherClass yoc = new YourOtherClass(1, 2);
YourClass yc = new YourClass("1234", "2345", "3456", yoc);
```

And then call the specific getter to receive a value with typesafety:

```
String a = yc.getA(); // works
Integer i = yc.getA(); // doesn't work
```

Or setting a new value via the setter:

```
yoc.setD1(4); // works
yoc.setD1("4"); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating things imo. You could do it in a very straightforward manner. One liners are not always the ideal solutions.

I don't have the possibility to compile it, but it should be ok.

```
public Optional<Integer> getInnerValue(Map<String, Object> map, String outerKey, String innerKey) {
    Object o = map.get(outerKey);
    if (!(o instanceof Map)) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(((Map)o).get(innerKey));
}
```

Using a one-liner

```
public Optional<Integer> getInnerValue(Map<String, Object> map, String outerKey, String innerKey) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(outerKey))
                   .filter(Map.class::isInstance)
                   .map(Map.class::cast)
                   .map(m -> m.get(innerKey))
                   .findFirst();
}
```